# Matplotlib patch `get_verts()` changes after adding patch to Axes

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to get the vertices of `matplotlib.patches.Ellipse` object by using the `get_verts()` function. Unfortunately the vertices have been changed after adding the ellipse to the `Axes`. Here is my code (Python 3.5):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

fig = Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

e = Ellipse((0,0), 100, 200)
print(e.get_verts())
[[   0.         -100.        ]
 [   2.48205003  -99.91768257]
 [   7.38744659  -98.94347052]
...,
 [  -7.38744659  -98.94347052]
 [  -2.48205003  -99.91768257]
 [   0.         -100.        ]]

ax.add_patch(e)
print(e.get_verts())
[[  8.00000000e+01  -3.83520000e+04]
 [  1.57066457e+02  -3.83518765e+04]
 [  3.11115446e+02  -3.83503961e+04]
 ..., 
 [ -1.51115446e+02  -3.83503961e+04]
 [  2.93354282e+00  -3.83518765e+04]
 [  8.00000000e+01  -3.83520000e+04]]
```

Does anyone understand this and/or know how to get the original vertices (before  the ellipse is added to the axes)?

Comment: Store original vertices before plotting. Vertices are changed because of transformation applied by axises when patch is drawing. Look at the return values of `get_transform()` for your ellipse.

Comment: That was also my first idea and that of course worked. I just thought there might be a nicer way of doing this.

Comment: If you use transformed after drawing vertices you need to apply on they an inverse transformation to get initial values.

Comment: Yes you are right. This is how it worked: ax.transData.inverted().transform(e.get_verts()) gives the original vertices